# Return a reactive property from store in a callback?

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to make the 'modal' that is returned to the callback, reactive. Is there a way? The underlying model in the state[] does not get updated when I call modal.isOpen = false for example.

## Store:

```js
const store = () => {
    const state: []
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(state)

    const openModal(data) {
        const modal = {
            isOpen: false,
            loading: false,
            onConfirm: data.onConfirm
        }
        return [...state, modal]
    }

    return {
        subscribe,
        set,
        update,
        openModal
    }
}
```

## Modal Component:

```js
{#each $modals as modal, i (modal)}

    <Modal bind:open={$modals[i].isOpen}>
        <Button
            on:click={() => $modals[i].onConfirm($modals[i])}
            bind:loading={$modals[i].loading}>
            Close
        </Button>
    </Modal>

{/each}
```

## Component:

```js
store.openModel({
    onConfirm: async ($modal) => {
        $modal.loading = true
        await doSomething()
        $modal.loading = false
        $modal.isOpen = false
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties `isOpen` and `isLoading` would have to be stores or you would have to reassign the entire store itself on every change (would not recommend that).

If you use stores for the properties you would have to extract the content of the `{#each}` into a separate component, so the stores can be assigned on the top level and be used with `$`-notation as in:

```html
<script>
  export let modal;

  $: ({ isOpen, isLoading } = modal)
</script>

<Modal bind:open={$isOpen}>...
```

In the callback, you then would have to use `$modal.isOpen.set(...)` etc.

Personally, I would not put all modals into one store, there seems to be little  value in that. I just construct each modal separately using a utility function that also takes care of destroying the modal, once it is closed (using the [client-side API](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api)).

E.g.

```js
function confirm(message, onConfirm) {
  // If you need context, get it beforehand with `getAllContexts` and
  // pass it as `context`
  const modal = new ConfirmModal({
    target: document.body,
    props: { message },
  });

  // If you need to modify component properties,
  // add <svelte:options accessors /> in the component
  modal.$on('confirm', () => onConfirm(modal))
  modal.$on('close', () => modal.$destroy());
}
```

You can also return a `Promise`, so you get an API like this:

```js
async function onSubmit() {
  const confirmed = await confirm('Really?');
  if (confirmed == false)
    return;

  // do something here
}
```

(This of course would not allow for adding some loading state to the dialog.)

Comment: Thanks for thorough response, I just wanted to achieve programmatic managing of modals from anywhere in the application so I chose stores. I'm yet to explore doing it this way with client-side api. If I wanted to retain a closing animation or loading, I suppose I could call modal.$set({loading: true}) or modal.$set({open:false}) ?

Comment: I also considered creating a class like ModalManager and making the class reactive with writable(this) in the constructor, I am not 100% sure if it would work, but have a hunch yes. But I think your suggestion will be cleaner because I won't have to have a 3rd code block on the base layout to recursively output modals from a store.

Comment: You can use `$set`, though as mentioned I would just add the `accessors` option, then you can just use `modal.loading = true` and `modal.open = false`. (This also allows reading properties, which otherwise is not possible.)